# 401 Unauthorized Error in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a new in Spring boot and Spring Security and I am having this error:

**" error 401 Unauthorized ( c.e.l.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource)**"

i tried this authentification & register tutorial ( https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/?unapproved=2080&moderation-hash=102a62e22b4c04ad25fce7fd2c3617a3#comment-2080) and an admin gestion users interface (https://www.javaguides.net/2020/01/spring-boot-angular-9-crud-example-tutorial.html ) **and it works as desired**.But when i add this crud tutorial to the authentification and register application to get a full application i get this error: **" Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource".**

I have the problem that when I'm **successfully** logged in, I want to make a request to get the list of users. the request I am sending is an secured GET request which is http://localhost:8084/loginsystem/api/list/employees this request is send by my **Angular frontend.**
But my problem now is, Spring Boot is telling me that the user isn't authorized and sending an 401 error. I'am sending an Authorization token when I make the request from frontend to backend.

Any help please i couldn’t resolve this problem i tried all solutions and it didn't solve the problem .

this is the POM.XML File

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <artifactId>loginsystem</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>loginsystem</name>
 <description>loginsystem projet mvc</description>

 <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
 
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
 
     
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
 <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
 <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
 <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
 
        
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

This is the result when i run the application on eclipse:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iqEt.png)

This is the architecture of the full application on eclipse:

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeZrt.png)

This is the postman result: 
[Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzeyM.png)

and this is the result on the browser (frontend side):
[Browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Txh9.png)

[image: header in postman]

[image: the authorization tab in postman]

Comment: In WebSecurityConfig file configure method it is mentioned to authenticate any request other than "/api/auth/**" and "/api/test/**". you are trying to get "api/list/employees" which must be authenticated. So I think you will need to pass the JWT token in the header with this request. First generate a JWT token and then pass in this request as Bearer token.

Comment: i'm new in spring security and i really don't know how to generate a JWT token and pass it in the request as Bearer token.Can u please show me an example and thank you so much for u help. @TusharJajodia

Comment: The tutorial you are follwing has the endpoint for generating the JWT token. Implement and try to use that endpoint to generate the token. Once you have the token pass it in the request HEADER as
Authorization : Bearer "Token value"
or see how to pass Bearer token in postman. ( you can use Authorization tab in postman as well)

Comment: i did that but the browser still show me this error : **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8084/loginsystem/api/list/employees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.** @TusharJajodia

Comment: Can you please try to hit the request from postman.

Comment: from postman it gives {"status" : 401 , "error" : "unauthorized", "message" : "Error: Unauthorized", "path": "/loginsystem/api/list/employees"} @TusharJajodia

Comment: can you attach the postman screenshot of header and Authorization Tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question resolved 
i added this code to the configure() method to webSecurityConfig class

```html
.antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER","MODERATOR").anyRequest().authenticated().and()
   
   .logout()
   .invalidateHttpSession(true)
   .clearAuthentication(true)
   .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
   .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
   .permitAll();
http.addFilterBefore( authenticationJwtTokenFilter(),  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```